# Using Repl It to click a button on webpage, and retriving infomation

Tags: python

How do you click a button on a webpage using Replit.

I've tried selenium but I don't get the webdriver to work/install, using replIt. And roaring the forums its seems like its not supported. 
Is request a option. As I googled it seems like it downloads all info, and cannot click on a button.

So my goal is to get a random quote from "https://inspirobot.me/", but that needs a press of a button. Is there a workaround there?, And then retrive the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `https://inspirobot.me/api?generate=true`

Embed it in some way, like this html

```
<img src="https://inspirobot.me/api?generate=true">
```